# Data transfers between From Azure to Onedrive

Tags: azure, onedrive

Does anyone know if the uploads from Azure to Onedrive are counted towards my Azure Egress quota?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Whenever data flows out of an Azure region, it is counted towards your egress quota and is billed accordingly.

Since Onedrive service is not an Azure service, any data that goes from Azure to Onedrive will be considered as data egress and will be counted towards your egress quota.

Answer (score 0):

I recently asked an Azure sales rep about this, because Google Cloud public provides that they do not charge for egress to Google services here:

https://cloud.google.com/vpc/network-pricing

I let the Azure sales rep know, and they pretended to not know what egress was and then said that if I didn't tell them the name of the company I was working for (likely so they could go over me and try to pitch directly the organization) that they didn't want to help me anymore. It was extremely predatory sales practices, when Google posts the information publicly. Because of this I could never recommend Azure to any company I work for.